# Android Navigation Drawer Fail

Tags: android, xml, integration, sidebar

I'm working on a chat-app and wanted to add a Navigation Drawer like in the GMail-App. I'm new to Java so pls don't kill me :D I tried to add it but it crashes :(

This is some of the code of my Chat.java

```
    public class Chat extends FragmentActivity {

final String[] data ={"Login","Register"};
final String[] fragments ={
        "com.linkr.chat.Login",
        "com.linkr.chat.Register"};
String username;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList();
public TextView chatTextArea;
TextView inputTextArea;
Button onClickButton;
Boolean isConnected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle("Linkr");
    /*<-- NAVDRAWER -->*/
    setContentView(layout.activity_chat);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(Chat.this, fragments[pos]));
                    tx.commit();
                }
            });
            drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
        }
    });
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(Chat.this, fragments[0]));
    tx.commit();
    /*<-- NAVDRAWER END -->*/
```

I also don't get how to use the NavigationDrawer.

This is my activity_chat.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".Chat"
            android:text = "Linkr">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                                        android:layout_height="800dp"
                                        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/onClickButton"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/onClickButton"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/chatTextArea"
        android:layout_above="@+id/onClickButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/onClickButton"/>
```

Do i need another XML for it? Can someone tell me how this works? 
Thank you guys! :)

Comment: post the stack trace of the error

Comment: I don't get any error :(

Comment: I tried to run it in android studio and it throws this: Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable main

Answer (score 1):

The `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` is designed to be the `top ViewGroup` and can have two childs. The first one is your `Content View` (The View which is visible), like the normal Activity layout. The second one is your `Drawer View` (The View you can pull from the side).

The Content View and the Drawer View can both be a ViewGroup like a RelativeLayout or a single view in your case the ListView.

So your layout should look like this:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <!-- YOUR CONTENT VIEW-->
            <RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".Chat"
                android:text = "Linkr">
        <EditText
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/inputTextArea"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/onClickButton"/>

        <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Send"
             android:id="@+id/onClickButton"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputTextArea"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputTextArea"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <EditText
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:ems="10"
             android:id="@+id/chatTextArea"
             android:layout_above="@+id/onClickButton"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputTextArea"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/onClickButton"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <--! YOUR DRAWER VIEW -->
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawer"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @Steve instead of listview I am using Linearlayout its crashing as 08-12 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{41971398 V.E...C. ...P...D 0,0-480,762 #7f070053 app:id/parent_drawer} is not a sliding drawer

Comment: @PadmaKumar Can you open up a new question with your problem? And please with some more details ;).